# How to draw a complicated table in latex?

Tags: tables

Please see the picture attached. How do I draw such a table in latex?

[image: Desired Table]

This what I have done so far.

```
\begin{tabular}{|c||c|}
\hline 
Experimental data & Theoretical predictions \tabularnewline
\hline 
\hline 
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
A & B & C & D & E & F\tabularnewline
\hline 
\hline 
 &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
 &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular} & %
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
G & H\tabularnewline
\hline 
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

This leads to,

[image: What i got]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. As it stands, the question looks like a "do-it-for-me" question and it might not be well received unless someone volunteers to provide an answer. To get higher changes of obtaining a reply, you could explain what you did so far and include a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/13304) to begin with.

Comment: This link https://nhigham.com/2019/11/19/better-latex-tables-with-booktabs/ has the source code for tables using the tabular and booktabs packages. Pick a version of one of these tables which you like best. Get it to run on your computer. Then read about the package so you can modify that table into the table you want. If you have difficulties, post what you have done here and ask a question.

Comment: Thank you Jay that works.

Comment: Your drawing has "Theory", while your work so far has "Theoretical Predictions".  The latter is much wider and causing difficulties.  Which do you actually want?  I echo the suggestion for booktabs.  But it's not clear to me if you're trying to create a blank table to pencil in values, or if you have the values in hand and just didn't share them in your post.

Comment: I have solved the problem now. Jay's suggestion worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to construct that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (however, I would recommend a design with only horizontal rules with the tools of the package `booktabs`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccccc@{}ccc}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=2pt]
\Block{1-6}{Experience} &&&&&& & \Block{1-2}{Theory}  \\ 
A & B & C & D & E & F & & G & H \\ 
\\
\\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want ?

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}


%\setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}

%\begin{table}[] %if you want
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|@{}c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Experience} & &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Theory}  \\ \hline
A & B & C & D & E & F &  &       G    &    H            \\ \hline
 &    & & &   &     &&&                         \\ \hline
&          &            &&&            &                        &  &                           \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
%\label{} \caption{} 
%\end{table}
\end{document}
```